# Why this C++ program complies and runs in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        cout<<"started "<<endl;
        int n= -2;
        int array[n];

        array[0]=100;
        array[1]=200;

        cout<<array[0]<<endl;
        cout<<array[1]<<endl;

        cout<<"over"<<endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Why does this compile and run? I expected a compilation error because value of `n` is negative.

Comment: Why does it matter? If you know it is wrong and produces undefined behavior, don't do it.

Comment: It isn't valid C++ even if `n` were positive.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, C++14 supports VLAs.

Comment: @BrianCain Citation needed.

Comment: @BrianCain, Nope, they got pulled out into a TS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable-length arrays are not a C++ feature, so this line will cause a compilation error in a compiler that is ordered to strictly adhere to the C++ specification, regardless of the value of `n` (unless `n` is `const` and can be determined at compile-time):

```
int array[n];
```

Likely you are using a compiler that supports variable-length arrays as an extension.  Therefore, the rules regarding what is valid depend entirely on the specific compiler and compiler options, and any code that you write using this extension will not be portable to compilers that don't support this non-standard feature.

Comment: I am using latest version of CodeBlock with MinGW

Comment: @alalamin Then you are using g++, which does support VLAs. However, I would strongly recommend that you avoid using them because your code may not work on any other compiler. If you need an array whose size you don't know at compile-time then you should use `std::vector`.